# Game sounds won't play on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 6 with up to date software. But every time I open a game, the music or sounds won't play. At first, I thought it was the problem with games, but I checked each of their settings and the music is on. So I turned the volume up on my phone, but it won't play. The volume works for my music apps or video apps just not for my games.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Try turning off the silent switch. Or if you have changed the setting, flick up and show Control Centre and ensure that sounds are on (meaning the icon is not highlighted. You must flick the switch towards yourself when the screen is facing you. It is located above the volume buttons close to the camera of the phone.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @bret7600 some people don't realise there are separate volume levels depending on software/functions. So, just to eliminate another obvious possibility, when playing one of the games turn the volume up to ensure that the speaker volume for games isn't turned down.

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off silent switch and turning up ringer volume.